# Embedded C GPIO Issue

Tags: c, embedded

I am having trouble with programming, as I am a beginner, and I am trying to read a square pulse train coming into one of my digital GPIO pins of my PIC microcontroller. I have to "sample" and then store the incoming signal so that I have a bunch of 1's and 0's saved (possibly in an array). I have to save the number of 1's and 0's I get(which are sampled in packets of 8, 4 times over) and calculate the number of 1's or 0's into an average.

Anyone know how I can either start of accomplish this in C code?

Comment: My problem is that I don't really know what I am doing and don't even have a starting point- if I had to say I had something it would be

Comment: You could at least write your thoughts out like what data structure you might want to use to store the sampled data, how you would calculate an average with it, etc... You could write some pseudo code as well and say you don't really know the syntax well enough to translate it into C

Answer (score 2):

I'd break it down into pieces.  Write something that reads the input line inside a loop:

```
unsigned int input;

for (;;)  /* infinite loop */
{
   input = ReadInput();
   printf ("%d\n",input);
}
```

You'll have to create something for ReadInput(), hopefully you have an example you can follow.  That will depend on the exact PIC you're using and which input line is being read.

Once you see it reads the input line correctly, then add a sleep() function to slow it down to something reasonable (your sample rate), change input into an array (`input[x++] = ReadInput();`), and figure out how you want the loop to end.  But this will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

If i would do this, i would probably set the GPIO ISR Handler to get an interrupt on the GPIO Pin each time the GPIO value changes, and have a timer in parallel counting. Then if the gpio value is changed, the interrupt fires and you can read the timer and just see how much time passed since the last GPIO change (and then you can sample that how ever you want). I think this is the most exact solution.